# How can I make a regex for one or more space delimited numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

No matter what I just can't figure it out.  I can have `\d` and then repeat it, but whatever gets repeated either has to have a trailing space, or it doesn't.

I want to be able to match any of the following:

```
"1"
"1 2"
"1 2 3"
"1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9    9"
```

(with arbitrary repetition)

But absolutely none of the following:

```
"1 "
"1 2 "
" 1 2"
" 1 3 4 56 6  "
```

How can this be done?

Perhaps the language which I would like to validate is simply irregular?

Comment: whats your current (not working) regex? also, can you have 2 digit numbers, or are they always 1 digit?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
^(\d\s+)*\d$
```

String must always end in a digit (no trailing space), for any digit before the end it must be followed by 1 to many spaces (and the initial number cannot be preceded by space)

Comment: if your sequence could validly have a `10, 12, 100` etc (2+ digit numbers), then change both `\d` to `\d+`

Answer (score 0):

I think this regexp should work for you:

```
/^(\d+\s*)*\d+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/(\d+ +)*\d+/
```

Comment: Won't that match `"5 6 "`?